# Resources for writing Play! models in Scala

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

There is virtually no documentation available for models in the *Play!* framework, particularly for Scala. What little is available is for Java or is outdated.

Are there any resources explaining how to write models in Scala for *Play!*?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the Anorm [documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.3/ScalaAnorm) is quite clear. Complement it with the code in the Samples folder of Play Framework and all the Anrom related questions in Stack Overflow.